# Error Paypal Call to a member function total() on null

Tags: laravel-5, paypal

Muy buenas noches a todos espero puedan ayudarme con este problema que me he encontrado al querer integrar pagos con paypal en mi tienda online, estoy realizando el cobro y debería redireccionarme a paypal para poder procesar el pago pero me encuentro con este error que no encuentro como resolverlo 
"Call to a member function total() on null" ese total es el precio total de los productos agregados en el carrito de ventas funciona en el carrito pero me manda el error en PayPal.php podrían decirme porque pasa esto y como puedo solucionarlo por favor.
[image: Error marcado en laravel 5.5]

```
<?php

namespace laravel;


class PayPal
{
    private $_apiContext;
    private $shopping_cart;
    private $_ClientId = "";
    private $_ClientSecret = "";


    public function _construct($shopping_cart){
        $this->_apiContext =\PaypalPayment::ApiContext($this->_ClientId,$this->_ClientSecret);
        $config = config("paypal_payment");
        $flatConfig = array_dot($config);
        $this->_apiContext->setConfig($flatConfig);

        $this->shopping_cart = $shopping_cart;
    }

    public function generate(){

      $payment = \PaypalPayment::payment()->setIntent("sale")
                 ->setPayer($this->payer())
                 ->setTransactions([$this->transaction()])
                 ->setRedirectUrls($this->redirectUrls());
         try{
            $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
         } catch(\Exception $ex){
            dd($ex);
            exit(1);
         }
         return $payment;
    }

    public function payer(){
       //Returns Payment's info

        return \PaypalPayment::payer()
                         ->setPaymentMethod("paypal");
    }
      public function RedirectUrls(){
        $baseURL = url('/');
        return \PaypalPayment::redirectUrls()
                            ->setReturnUrl("$baseURL/payments/store")
                            ->setCancelUrl("$baseURL/store/cart");
    }
    public function transaction(){
        //Returns transaction's info
        return \PaypalPayment::transaction()
                  ->setAmount($this->amount())
                  ->setItemList($this->items())
                  ->setDescription("tu") 
                         ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    }

    public function items(){
        $items = [];
        $productos = $this->shopping_cart->productos()->get();
        foreach($productos as $producto){
            array_push($items, $producto->paypalItem());
        }
        return \PaypalPayment::itemList()->setItems($items);
    }
    public function amount(){
        return \PaypalPayment::amount()->setCurrency("USD")
          ->setTotal($this->shopping_cart->total());
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace laravel\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use laravel\ShoppingCart;
use laravel\PayPal;
use laravel\User;
class ShoppingCartController extends Controller
{
    public function index($name){
        $shopping_cart_id = \Session::get('shopping_cart_id');
        $shopping_cart = ShoppingCart::findOrCreateBySessionID($shopping_cart_id);

        $paypal = new PayPal($shopping_cart);
        $paypal->generate();
        return redirect($payment->getApprovalLink());
        return"";

       // $productos = $shopping_cart->productos()->get();

        //$total = $shopping_cart->total();


       // $user =User::select()
        //->where('name','=',$name)
        //->first();

       //return view ("store.cart",compact("productos","total","user"));
    }   
}
```

```
<?php

namespace laravel;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShoppingCart extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["status"];

    public function inShoppingCarts(){
        return $this->hasMany("laravel\InShoppingCart");
    }

     public function productos(){
        return $this->belongsToMany("laravel\Producto","in_shopping_carts");
    }

    public function productsSize(){
        return $this->productos()->count();
    }
    public function total(){
        return $this->productos()->sum("costo_unitario"); //total que declaro en Paypal.php-> public function amount 
    }
    public static function findOrCreateBySessionID($shopping_cart_id){

        if($shopping_cart_id)
           //Buscar el carrito
            return ShoppingCart::findBySession($shopping_cart_id);
            else
           //Crear un carrito
                return ShoppingCart::createWithoutSession();
    }
    public static function findBySession($shopping_cart_id){
        return ShoppingCart::find($shopping_cart_id);
    }

    public static function createWithoutSession(){
        return ShoppingCart::create(["status"=>"incompleted"]);
    }
}
```